# xdmp:diacritic-less giving unexpected results

Tags: marklogic

I am using `ML 8.0-6.3`

character: `ı`

word: `Araştırmalari`

`xdmp:diacritic-less()` is not converting the above diacritic character to lower case `i`

Initially I thought it is not a valid diacritic character. But as per this site [diacritic characters](http://pinyin.info/unicode/diacritics.html) it is a valid diacritic.

In the link see the line

> 0131  ı   dotlessi    lowercase DOTLESS I

Please put more light on this.

Due to this `diacritic-insensitive` query is not working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Usually one would expect a diacritic to be removed, but there isn't a diacritic there to be removed that I can see.

Anyway, this is covered by the Unicode standard, not whether it looks similar. Take a look at [Block U0100](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0100.pdf).  You need to be able to decompose the character into its base character and diacritic like 0130.  0131 doesn't have that, not even at compatibility level.

Info on the charts is at [About the Unicode charts](https://www.unicode.org/charts/About.html).

Comment: `ı` this is the diacritic character, I am facing issue with.
In the link you have provided, there also it's available.

Comment: What shows that ı is a diacritic?  If you look at 0130 you see the three lines symbol.  That shows decomposition to a base character 0049 and a combining diacritic 0307.  What indicates that i is the diacriticless version of ı (or vice versa)?

Answer (score 1):

The dotless i is kind of strange.

https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0100.pdf

> 0131 ı LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I
>
> - Turkish, Azerbaijani
> - uppercase is 0049 I
>
> → 0069 i  latin small letter i

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I

> In normal typography, when lower case i is combined with other diacritics, the dot is generally removed before the diacritic is added; however, Unicode still lists the equivalent combining sequences as including the dotted i, since logically it is the normal dotted i character that is being modified.
>
> Most Unicode software uppercases ı to I and lowercases İ to i, but, unless specifically configured for Turkish, it lowercases I to i and uppercases i to I. Thus uppercasing then lowercasing, or vice versa, changes the letters.

So, although it is not a diacritic character, you could run the string through a series of calls to change upper/lower case, which results in converting `ı` to `I` and then `i`.

`upper-case("Araştırmalari") => lower-case() => xdmp:diacritic-less()` would produce: `arastirmalari`

However, that would result in a `lower-case()` string value, that is probably not what you want, but if using as a search term, may work for you.

**A better solution:**

If there are specific (non-diacritic) characters, such as the dotless i `ı`, that are not normalized to the expected character through the invocation of `xdmp:diacritic-less()`, **you could apply your own character substitutions after normalizing the diacritic characters using [`fn:translate()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-translate):**

```
fn:translate(xdmp:diacritic-less("Araştırmalari"), "ı", "i")
```

which returns: `Arastirmalari`

Comment: Thank you Hansen for the explanation. I am not able to achieve one thing, please help me out in building the sol.
XMLs are stored with dotless i `ı` character, the requirement is, for the search term with normal `i` also bring xmls which contains `ı`.
like search for `Araştirmalari` also matches `Araştırmalari`

Comment: If you have implemented the Envelope pattern, you could translate the original text into your normalized “search friendly” form, so that user searches would match on either the original and/or the normalized values. Alternatively, you could intercept search requests and try rewriting to apply OR queries with permutations of the search values. If you can, probably easier to store normalized form in the Envelope or document properties and search against that in addition to, or instead of, the original text.